# How to show loading image/spinner on click of a button in Angular2 template until the response is received from server

Tags: angular

Please note: Request is not AJAX request. I am making HTTP GET call to backend Webservice to get the response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a div with a high z-index, position absolute and a width/height of 100% (see example less below). Then in your component create a `loading$` observable:

```
let loading$: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

in your data fetching method do:

```
getServerData(params: any) {
  this.loading$.next(true);
  this.http.get(url, params)
    .do(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    .subscribe(<your original handler>);
```

To instantiate the spinner, put

```
<div class="loading-spinner" *ngIf="loading$ | async"></div>
```

and example of less for the spinner:

```
.loading-spinner {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 1.5s loader linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much @Meir. It worked for me. I used <div [class.loading-spinner]="loading$ | async"></div> to add the class conditionally though.

Comment: nice idea :) Yet, would you prefer to leave an empty div?

Comment: :) I tried that bcoz I thought ngIf is not working ....but I retested now and it also works :)

Comment: This loading spinner works fine until my response received is correct ....but when my backend service sends a response status as 404 and with text content type...and when I throw this error as Observable.throw(error.text()) ...This error is displayed in my view but the spinner doesnt disappear...Not sure why is condition not set to false when an error is thrown...Can you pls explain me this.

Comment: add a `catch(..)` close similar to the `do(...)` or use finally

Comment: finally property is not there ....In catch I was calling handleError function where I return error (Observable.throw(error.text())). I dont have acces to loading$ there...Please can you post some code for it...Sorry but I am very new to Angular2

Comment: No worries, this is the way to learn. Can you post the full code, including the catch so I can help

Comment: In my Component I call the service method passing the loading$

Comment: In my Component I call the service method passing the loading$                    this.myservice.search(name,loading$)..do(() => this.loading$.next(false))
    .subscribe(<myoriginal handler>); In my service search method before calling the http get I set the loading$ true                 loading$.next(true);
        return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(response => response.json())
           .catch(this.handleError);                                                                  And in handleError method I just return Observable.throw(error.text());

Comment: Great, so in your catch handler, before invoking the nandler, set the loading to false: .catch(v => {loading$.next(false);this.handleError(v);})

Comment: That gives me an error .[ts] Argument of type '(v: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<ModelArray[]>) => ObservableInput'.
       Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'